# Extension Installer Issue (Magento Connect Manager)

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, multistore, magento-community

Issue with magento connect manager. In admin panel, when you go to System --> Magento Connect --> Magento Connect Manager. It redirects you to the following URL:[http://thepoultryhatchery.com/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fthepoultryhatchery.com%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emAI8.png)

my url is: www.ThePoultryHatchery.com

Site is in maintenance mode so you must go to thepoultryhatchery.com/index.php if you need to see site. Setup in Multi-Store using 1 back-end but two stores due to pricing being different for store pick up / shipping.

Attached is screen shot of what it does. It seems its a redirect to a 404 Not found 1 Error. Anyone have a solution to fix this issue? I don't think any files are missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated? Is there another method of installing extensions other than this option or is it required?

@JELLEJ  - htaccess file: http://www.filedropper.com/htaccess_2

[image]

Comment: Looks like it could be an issue with your .htaccess, whatever you are doing to redirect the maintenance mode is what is causing your issue. Disable it to confirm, then work around it by implementing the correct variables to allow access.

Comment: @sr_magento We are not redirecting/maintenance mode by .htaccess. we are using index.html for it. Ill try it, but not sure if that's the solution to our issue.

Comment: @sr_magento didnt work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm sure there is something going on with your htaccess or rewrites. Please check this.

If you want to access your downloader; go to the following URL: http://thepoultryhatchery.com/downloader/index.php

**EDIT**
Please add your .htaccess if you want us to have a look at it.

Comment: ive updated it to add my htaccess file. i grabbed it from my cpanel file  under public_html. is that the correct one?

Comment: @JefferyB your htaccess should work again if you change the index.html directoryindex to index.php , your downloader will also work :) perhaps use http://inchoo.net/magento/maintenance-mode-in-magento/ for maintenance mode :)

Comment: trying now. Will let u know :)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU! WOOHOO :) Only took like 3 weeks to get a solution lol.

Comment: No problemo :) enjoy your Magento store!